# Cypress not intercepting request with render function vue

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to do a pretty simple intercept in Cypress using a Vue's application. My component has a setup method using render function as such:

```
setup() {
   useInfiniteLoading({ runner: ... })
}
```

Then on my tests I do the following:

```
describe("List todo resource", () => {
    it("Checks it loads more todos when scrolling to the bottom", function () {
      cy.intercept('/todo').as('getTodos');
      cy.visit("/todos");
      cy.wait("@getTodos").then(({response}) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
    })
})
```

When running the test I see that the `intercept` is not stubbing the response.

[image]

As you can see from the image the request makes a request to my actual server running locally and the response is stubed. The weird part is that in a previous test I have:

```
it("Checks the todo list gets updated when clicking on to resolve it (from true to false)", function () {
    cy.visit("/todos");

    const resolved = false;
    const shouldHaveClass = resolved
      ? "mdi-checkbox-marked-outline"
      : "mdi-checkbox-blank-outline";

    cy.intercept("GET", "todo", {
      fixture: "resources/todo/list.todo.json",
    }).as("getTodos");

    cy.intercept("PUT", "todo", {
      body: { data: { ...this.updateTodoFixture.data, resolved } },
    }).as("updateTodo");

    cy.get(".todo-list-item__resolve")
      .first()
      .each((btn) => {
        btn.click();
      });

    cy.get(".todo-list-item__resolve")
      .first()
      .should("satisfy", ($el) => {
        const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList);

        return classList.includes(shouldHaveClass);
      });
  });
```

And the response is stubbed using `intercept` as you can see from the previous screenshot. Is it possible that the previous test is affecting the next test? I have tried taking a look into ["Intercept too soon"](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#the-intercept-was-registered-too-late) but no luck on trying to apply the fix described in the page.

Any idea on what could be causing the stub not to happen?